# 2d Integer array not running properly java android

Tags: java, arrays

I am using an array like this:

```
int selIntIndex = Integer.valueOf(selStringIndex);

        int[][] PreIntVal = new int[][]


                {
                 { selIntIndex,
                        2 },
                 {
                        selIntIndex,
                        3 },
                 {
                        selIntIndex,
                        1 } };

        PreIntVal[3][0] = PreIntVal[4][0] = 3;

        android.util.Log.d("StripedLog",
                Arrays.toString(Values.PreStringVal[3]));
```

But somehow the code never reaches the "log" statement. The problem is with this line:  PreIntVal[3][0] = PreIntVal[4][0] = 3; because if I comment it out, it works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular line `PreIntVal[3][0] = PreIntVal[4][0]` is causing [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). Look at the defined array's dimensions : `new int[][]  {
                 { selIntIndex,
                        2 },
                 {
                        selIntIndex,
                        3 },
                 {
                        selIntIndex,
                        1 } };`. It seems you are confused as to how to access the array elements using *index* , please go through [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

The valid indexes for this array are *[0,1,2][0,1]*.

Observe this diagram to understand how the indexes are mapped.

[image]